# Автоматическое завершение консольного приложения Qt

Tags: qt, c++

После выполнения всего кода приложение (Qt, консольное) закрывается только закрытием окошка. Как это истправить. На app.quit() и app.exit() не реагирует.

Answer (score 2):

app.exit() только вызывает завершение app.exec(), а завершаются кутешные программы точно так же, как и обычные -- возвратом значения из main()

Если вы в своей программе не выполняли app.exec(), то и app.exit() делать не нужно

Answer (score 1):

Послать окошку сообщение "закрыться"?

Comment: Послать с помощью emit? Думал... А от кого послать? Не соображу(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте QCoreApplication::exit();

**UPD:** Верните из функции main 0, вместо app.exec();

Comment: По сути я-то так и делаю. 
QCoreApplication app;
.
.
.
app.exit();
Не работает.
Или я не прав?

Comment: Не совсем так, QCoreApplication::exit(); это вызов статического метода, можно вызвать из любой части кода. <br/> *UPD* Хотя в документации написано что этот вызов эквивалентен вызову app.quit();

Comment: Ясно.Попробовал. Результат тот же.

Comment: А где пытаетесь сделать выход? Что если Вы будете возвращать в функции main 0, а не app.exec();? Такой выход устроит?

Comment: Да в принципе устроит. Я так и сделал пока. Просто хотелось разобраться.